# Swapping between shift operators and math operators

Tags: visual-c++

In the screenshot I provided I'm simply trying to figure out if I can use "=" in the place of >> or <<. If not what's the difference of usage? *Thanks*.
Here is a link :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pefLm.png)

```
string snumb= "100";
int myint;
myint=stringstream(snumb);
cout << myint + 1 << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

- `a << b` means that you send b to a (which needs to be able to receive some flow of information).
- `a = b` means that you affect b to variable a.
- `a >> b` means that you read from a (which needs to be provide a flow of information, i.e., be able to be read from) and send to b.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that means that I can't use << or >> except in cin and cout commands but not between variables such as number1 and number2?!